# how to set name to each event.target.value in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm learning `react` and made some components with inputs. I have several events where i use `event.target.value`, But the problem is that they overwrite each other.

How can I set a specific name for each `event.target.value`, something like `event.target.myname.value`

To understand in more detail please see here [Code in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jjrtty)

Below is the code that I need to change and make events here with some kind of identifier so that they are not overwritten with other values.

```
class Range extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label for="f-size">Font size(from 1 to 50): {event.target.value}px</label>
        <input
          type="range"
          id="f-size"
          defaultValue="14"
          name="fsize"
          min="1"
          max="50"
          onChange={(event)=>this.props.fzCallback(event.target.value)}
        />
        <p style={{ fontSize: `${event.target.value}px`}}>
          Test text for font size range input.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Range;
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fz: '',
    };
  }
  handleFz = (fzData) => {
    this.setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, fz: fzData }));
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>          
          <Range fzCallback={this.handleFz} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me solve this.

Comment: Your code example in stackblitz looks differently and doesn't reproduce the problem, nothing is overwritten there

Comment: when I enter a number in the first input it affects the font size in the 
range component. I didn't paste all the code here because it would be too much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the Window `event` property which returns the current Event the handled by the site. (More on that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event)

The way to fix your problem is passing props to your child components.

So for example the `Range` component would look like that:

```
class Range extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label for="f-size">Font size(from 1 to 50): {this.props.value}px</label>
        <input
          type="range"
          id="f-size"
          defaultValue="14"
          name="fsize"
          min="1"
          max="50"
          onChange={(event)=>this.props.fzCallback(event.target.value)}
        />
        <p style={{ fontSize: `${this.props.value}px`}}>
          Test text for font size range input.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And your `App` component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inp: '',
      bg: '',
      fc: '',
      fz: '',
    };
  }
  handleColor = (colorData) => {
    this.setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, fc: colorData }));
  };
  handleBg = (bgData) => {
    this.setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, bg: bgData }));
  };
  handleFz = (fzData) => {
    this.setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, fz: fzData }));
  };
  handleCallback = (childData) => {
    this.setState({ inp: childData });
  };
  handleReset = () => {
    this.setState({ inp: '' });
  };
  render() {
    const divStyle = {
      color: this.state.fc,
      backgroundColor: this.state.bg,
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={divStyle}>
          <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
          <Input
            parentCallback={this.handleCallback}
            parentReset={this.handleReset}
          />
          <Result title={this.state.inp} />
          <Select colorCallback={this.handleColor} bgCallback={this.handleBg} />
          <Range value={this.state.fz} fzCallback={this.handleFz} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I needed! It may have been a simple mistake, but I'm still learning. Thanks for the help!